# How to Blink cursor on text box in wpf using mvvm pattern

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, styles

How to Blink cursor on the textbox when it gets to focus on mouse enter in WPF using MVVM pattern.
The following is my code

```
    <TextBox Name="txtUserName" IsManipulationEnabled="True"  Tag="{lex:Loc Key=EnterYourUsername}"  TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource LoginByDomaintxt}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="#111111">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the cursor blink by default styles.

```
<Textbox Name="Name"/>
```